# How to mark files in irfanview?

Tags: images, selection, irfanview

I need to sort photos.  Right now I use `Irfanview` tool to look through images.  I use `Del` key to move (delete) images into Recycle Bin.  I use `Del` key on images I like, since there are many less than I actually took.  I then restore them out of Recycle Bin into a separate folder.  That folder is my selected images.

I hate using delete, both mentally (pressing delete on a good image eh...), and physically (what happens with bits on disk being moved into potentially volatile space).

Is there a way to press something else, not delete images, but mark them for ease for transfer to a separate folder?

Comment: With an image loaded, press F8 to copy it. That brings up a dialog where you can set up 14 folders that you want to copy files to. Having chosen destination folders, you can then go to the next image, press F8 then the number that represents the destination folder you want to copy to.  Boom.

Comment: The idea of using the Recycle Bin as a temporary holding folder makes my skin crawl, too.  Here’s a warning for you: Once, I dragged a very large file (e.g., a virtual machine image) to the Recycle Bin, and Windows decided “That file would make the Recycle Bin bigger than it’s allowed to be, so I’ll just delete it.”  But *moving* a file around a filesystem should not cause the data contents to be copied — it should be just a matter of adjusting directory pointers.

Comment: I still use the Recycle Bin occasionally for this.  I try not to, but it's so simple - click Del to "save" the file, then move files out of Recycle Bin to whatever folder you need.  I totally get how skin-crawling it can be.... I don't like the SHIFT-X method described in the accepted answer, since a few times pressing a wrong key combo or escaping out at the very end of a very selection process resets entire selection in IrfanView (ouch).  So I have been trying to start using Adobe Lightroom for this type of task.  Lightroom though is a bit heavy on interface and learning curve though

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Q: How can I tag a file during browsing?

A: See the Hotkeys help file page. Tag a file with X, untag with SHIFT+X, use SHIFT+Q to show all tagged files in Thumbnails window.

From the [Official Irfanview FAQ](http://www.irfanview.com/faq.htm#Q22)

Comment: A word of warning - Tags aren't persistent between sessions. If you close Irfanview the selection will be lost.